# Webpack: Loading external JSON without bundling

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building my first one-page site using redux + deku and I need to internationalize it. I want to have a json file with all the texts, something like this:

```
# http://mysite.me/assets/i18n.json
{
  "en": {
    "greeting": "Hello"
  },
  "es": {
    "greeting": "Hola"
  }
}
```

Ideally I can require it in my boot file:

```
const T = require('/assets/i18n.json')
setTranslation(T)
```

But it mustn't be bundled in the same file, it should remain an external dependencies and it should load at runtime, so that I can edit it without needing to recompile the entire app!

Is it possible with webpack? Is my only option to include it directly in the HTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

For now this last solution is ok, but I was thinking on splitting the translations per main components, therefore the ability to include it directly through js would be nice.

Thanks to anyone who will help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would either to not `require` the file but instead [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) (or some other request method) and then exclude JSON from webpack.

The other way would be to split the code using the common chunks plugin for webpack. Your webpack config would look something like this:

```
entry: {
    app: './index.jsx',
    i18n: [
        'en',
        'fr',
        '...others'
    ]
},
output: {
    path: '/path/to/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

See the [official docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/code-splitting) for more information

Comment: Uhm, yes, I suppose `fetch` would be the right tool for the eventual splitting. Thanks :)