# Syntax Error on dynamic import() using webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm attempting to use a dynamic import to plug our server-generated `config.js` file into our production build of our app.

I attempt to use it in this way:

```
import('./config').then(function(config){
    //create a global config variable
    config = config;
})
```

(for now)

When I run `webpack`, I get the following error

`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected { (1:6)`

[Research](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/493) has led me to believe that this has something to do with `babel-loader` perhaps not playing nice with dynamic import, but I thought that had already been "solved" with a newer version.

Solutions seem to potentially have been to install [Syntax Dynamic Import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) or maybe [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node), but it's not clear to me which one or why.

Relevant bits of my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node config/webpack/build.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "amdi18n-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.6",
    "promise-polyfill": "^7.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.3",
    "chromedriver": "^2.34.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "madge": "^2.0.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "source-map-support": "*",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

We split our webpack.conf.js into **webpack.base.conf**

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const utils = require('./utils');
const config = require('../');

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '../..', dir);
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    enforce: 'pre',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
    options: {
        formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
        emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
    }
});

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/ide.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
            : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.less'],
        alias: {
            '@': resolve('public/js'),
        },
        modules: ['less', 'node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('public/js'), resolve('test')],
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "public/js/config.js")
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                use: ['raw-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false,
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty'
    }
};
```

...and **webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
        chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': env
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            },
            sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
            parallel: true
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
                ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
                : { safe: true }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
                ? 'public/html/ide.html'
                : config.build.index,
            template: 'public/html/ide.html',
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
            },
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/fonts'),
                to: config.build.assetsFonts,
            },
            {
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/img'),
                to: config.build.assetsImg,
            }
        ])
    ]
});
```

In [1](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/493), a user indicated that babel-loader should "just work" with dynamic imports now, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Something out of date? Something weird in my config?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/ should be what you want. Did that not work? Also in your example, `config = config;` does not make sense, since it's a local variable it will not update anything in the outer scope.

Comment: Do you want to load this file dynamic on runtime and not bundle it with webpack? Currently you are just putting it in a different chunk, but webpack still tries to load it at build.

Comment: Oh, @lukas-reineke yes. I want to load the file WELL after compilation - it is a file that can be updated any time by the server, and I don't want to recompile. Hmm, if I'm just putting it in another chunk, how do I separate it entirely? I was told to use dynamic import for this.

Comment: @logansfsmyth Thanks, I'll try this. As for `config=config`, my understanding is that declaring a variable without `var, const, let` makes it a global variable. Lemme try this in a repl real quick.

Comment: @loganfsmyth see https://repl.it/@CalebRogers/BustlingDelectablePhase

Comment: @komali_2 That is true if it isn't declared already, but since you already used that name as a function argument name, you're just re-assigning the value of the function argument.

Comment: shit you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

First, like some people in the comments mentioned, you need to use a different variable name for your config. Also, if you use `import` this way, the object you get is a ES6 exported object, so your data will be in `default`

```
import('./config').then(function(localConfig){
    //create a global config variable
    config = localConfig.default;
})
```

Next, the error you are getting is the result of babel not using the correct preset. You need to be at least on stage-2 for this to work.

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: ['es2015','stage-2']
    }
    include: [resolve('public/js'), resolve('test')],
    exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "public/js/config.js")
    ],
},
```

This will solve your error, but is still not what you want. All that is happening now is that webpack will split your config file into its own chunk, making a new http request on runtime to get this file. But it will not use the config file that is on the server, but the generated chunk from the build.
To load the actual config that you have on the server on runtime, you need to make a normal http request in your app.
Here is a good stackoverflow answer about this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725115/9083959